# Ran "Grant all privileges" but still getting "permission denied for relation"

Tags: postgresql, permissions, select

I'm using PostGres 9.5.  I'm confused about how to grant all privileges to a user for a particular database.  I thought this would do the trick

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO cindex;
GRANT
postgres=# \q
localhost:cindex davea$ cindex
psql (9.5.0, server 9.5.1)
Type "help" for help.

cindex=> select * FROM crypto_currencies;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation crypto_currencies
cindex=>
```

but as you can see, I'm still getting "permission denied for relation" when I try and SELECT something.  What else do I need to do to allow the user to select properly from all the tables in the database?

Comment: `set search_path` to public and try again. Also check the schema for `crypto_currencies`